# What is the name of the term for character facial expressions showing meaning in a play?

Tags: literature, literary-techniques, literary-english, obscure-terms

Last year I learnt the term for a character's facial expressions showing the audience what they feel, as well as their tone of voice in the stage directions when reading a play. I am currently writing a dissertation and cannot for the life of me remember what the terms were, and cannot find anything online; all i remember is that at least one of them started with a 'p'. Could anyone please help me and tell me what these terms are? 
Thank you all :)

Comment: "Indeed, the study of thousands of stage directions does not elicit a technical backstage vocabulary that is the exclusive property of one or another group of theatrical professionals or is linked to specific venues." [*A Dictionary of Stage Directions ...*](http://www.sddictionary.com/excerpts.html) That said, perhaps you're referring to 'gestural' stage directions (includes facial expressions), also known as 'pantomimic' directions. 'Delivery' directions might be used to refer to tone of voice directions. I could be misunderstanding your question entirely, though.

Comment: Have a look at the answer.

Comment: Are you talking about "miming"?  See also "mugging", defn 7 here http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mugging

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions

[countenance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/countenance) - the face as an indication of mood, emotion, or character

[physiognomy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/physiognomy)- the facial features held to show qualities of mind or character by their configuration or expression

The verb is physiognomize.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an outdated term you may try '[look](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look)'.

> [WITH OBJECT] *dated* Express (something) by one’s gaze:
> *'Poirot looked a question'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look

Answer (score 0):

[***persona***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona)

> 1. pl. *per·so·nas* or *per·so·nae* (-nē) The character represented by the voice of the speaker in a literary work.
> 2. *personae* The characters in a dramatic or literary work.
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/persona)
>
> :  **the personality that a person (as an actor or politician) projects in public :  image** (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persona)

Answer (score 0):

***Body language*** includes *a character's facial expressions showing the audience what they feel*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_language):

> **Body language** is a kind of nonverbal communication, where thoughts,
>   intentions, or **feelings** **are expressed by** physical behaviors, such as
>   **facial expressions**, body posture, gestures, eye movement, touch and
>   the use of space.